# failed: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip

I get a long error message when i'm trying to manually upgrade my pip version running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` but i'm not sure what is going wrong here..

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 407, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 73, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 773, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 730, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 647, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 428, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 428, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 417, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 317, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 247, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 396, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
```

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling pip following these directions.

1. uninstall current pip:

> python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools

2. download get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
3. execute get-pip script:

> python get-pip.py